# Show image with jquery on a specific date and don't show it after this day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, date

I am trying to make some kind of an advent calendar, where an image are shown on a specific date and then remove the day after where a new one is shown.

I have this code

```
var now = new Date();

var october1 = new Date("October 28, 2015");
var october2 = new Date("October 29, 2015");


if(now > october1) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.image1').show();
}


if(now > october2) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.image2').show();
}
```

This doesn't remove image from the day before, which means on october 29th it will show two images (from the 28th and 29th).

How can I schedule this, so I can show ONE new image each day?

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0m8Lk5d1/)

Comment: This should really be done on the server using PHP or ASP, otherwise a tiny hacker could display all images.

Comment: i think it's about Christmas messages not  for nuclear codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toDateString()` event and compare if same date. Try:

```js
var now = new Date().toDateString();
var october1 = new Date("October 28, 2015").toDateString();
var october2 = new Date("October 29, 2015").toDateString();


if(now != october1) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.image1').show();
}


if(now != october2) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.image2').show();
}
```

```css
.imageClass {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageClass image1">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LkmcILl.jpg" />
</div>



<div class="imageClass image2">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bAZWoqx.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can see more informations here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Comment: This seems to display the image from october 28th (image1) instead of the image that should be shown on the 29th (image2), which is today?

And if I add a new image for tomorrow october 30th it will show, the images for yesterday and tomorrow instead of showing the image for today.

See this FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0m8Lk5d1/1/

Comment: This could work.
It seems to display the correct image.
I will just check it tomorrow and see if it displays the correct image. If it I will accept this answer

Comment: ok. if you want is working today you can use `setDate()`. please try   https://jsfiddle.net/on6zn7co/

Answer (score 1):

> How can I schedule this, so I can show ONE new image each day?

Here is another approach you could take.

Instead of having a large number of `img` elements in your markup and then checking each day to show/hide those elements, you can just keep a library of your images with dates in an object array and then dynamically show just the image you need in just one `img` element.

**Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/0m8Lk5d1/4/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```js
var imageLibrary = [
        {'dt': '20151028', 'src': '//placehold.it/120x120?text=28' }, 
        {'dt': '20151029', 'src': '//placehold.it/120x120?text=29' }, 
        {'dt': '20151030', 'src': '//placehold.it/120x120?text=30' }
    ], 
    showImage, img, today = new Date(), search, 
    d = today.getDate().toString(), 
    m = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString(), 
    y = today.getFullYear().toString()
;
search = y + (m[1] ? m : "0" + m[0]) + (d[1] ? d : "0" + d[0]);
showImage = imageLibrary.filter(function(obj) { return (obj.dt === search); });
img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = showImage[0].src;
document.getElementById('imageWrap').appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="imageWrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in a simple way

make them hide by css first than use

```
if (new Date() < new Date(2018,9,28)){  
       $('.image1').show(); // This will show after October 28, 2015
       alert('hi')
   }

   if (new Date() < new Date(2018,9,29)){  //This will show after October 29, 2015
       $('.image2').show();
       alert('hello')
   }
```

[here the fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/91joxgsc/)

Comment: It is already hidden with css.
But it still shows the image from the day before.

I couldn't get your code to work?
Can you make a fiddle with your working code?

Answer (score -1):

your logic is incomplete

as i understand there are 2 condition
1. you want to show .image1 on 28-oct and 
2. .image2 after 28-oct
so your login should be like this

```
if(now > october1 && now<october2) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.image1').show();
}


if(now > october2) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.image2').show();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question:
How can I schedule this, so I can show ONE new image each day?

This means on october 28th one given image should be shown. On October 29th one NEW image should be shown, and only this image, it should not be shown with the image from yesterday or the image for tomorrow etc.